# How to set minutes for Remaining Work on TFS?

Tags: time, tfs

In TFS, the Remaining Wokrk field is a Double.
How can I set minutes for it?

For quarters of hours this is "easy" (or less difficult)
1h30 = 1,**5**
1h45 = 1,**75**

But, Ex: 
10min = 0,17
20min = 0,33 
It's hard!

Suggestions? Or am I overreacting?

Comment: Why would you want to track it down to mins? That's too granular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you need such a level of precision? I personally only deal in hours, although I know people who do deal in half hours.

I rarely have any task in development that will take less than 30 minutes, and if I did, I would just round it up. I would not expect anyone to have a lot of tasks taking under 30 minutes, if you do, perhaps your tasks are too granular. My tasks are often 2/3 hours in size and I just change them to 0, when complete, or update remaining hours at the end of the day, or if I realise I have underestimated and need to add more on. I do not perform periodic updates through the day because they don't really benefit anyone.

Remaining work in TFS is expected to be used as part of the [burn down chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn_down_chart) to show the estimated number of hours remaining, so long as you are tracking on the line it doesn't really matter.

I all comes down to how you have to work, if you are free to adopt the agile principles, then just stick with hours/halves, if you have management that require to the minute remaining, then you will have to go with the way you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dave, no need to track at the minute granularity.

And if for some reason you really do need to track at that level, there is nothing saying that Remaining Work has to be entered in hours.  It's just a numeric field, you could enter hours, minutes, days, whatever, so long as everybody consistently uses the same unit (I think there may be a couple reports that show it as hours, but as far as TFS is concerned it doesn't have to be hours if you don't want it to be).